# Website seems to not display css and js on Safari desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, desktop

I have a problem and I don't understand why.

I have a website [www.vtc-ideal-driver.com](https://www.vtc-ideal-driver.com)
And it seems to display wrong the CSS and the JS doesn't work in Safari desktop (not mobile).

It worked before and now nothing.

Could you help me?

I really don't understand.

Answer (score -1):

Check for syntax errors: Make sure that all of your CSS and JS files are free of syntax errors. You can use a tool like JSLint or CSSLint to check for errors.

Clear the browser cache: Sometimes, the browser cache can cause issues with CSS and JS loading correctly. Try clearing the cache in Safari by going to Safari > Clear History.

Check for compatibility issues: Make sure that your CSS and JS are compatible with Safari desktop. You can check for compatibility issues by testing your website in other browsers like Chrome and Firefox.

Check for browser extensions: Sometimes, browser extensions can cause issues with CSS and JS loading correctly. Try disabling any extensions you have installed in Safari and see if that fixes the problem.

Check your server logs: Check your server logs to see if there are any errors or warnings related to the CSS and JS files. This can help you identify any issues with file permissions or server configuration.

Comment: Please don't answer questions like this with generic answers that attempt to cover all of the bases. It's not helpful to future visitors because they won't know which of the half dozen checks solved the problem. The question needs to be specific enough to provide an answer unique to the question. If it's not, then the question should be closed until it can be edited so that it meets the criteria. See [answer] for more.